# how mzlib/etc's identity works?

Tags: racket

In one [web program](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5510/server.rkt) , there is code fragment as follows:

```
(require mzlib/etc)
(define (h-handler base args)
 (do-h identity))

(define (do-h cont)
  [begin
    (printf "~e\n" cont)
  (web-read/k "First number"
              (lambda (v1)
                (web-read/k "Second number"
                            (lambda (v2)
                              (cont (number->string (+ v1 v2)))))))])
```

Comment: FYI, if you're using the `#lang racket` language, `identity` is built-in so you don't need `mzlib/etc`, which is mostly deprecated. You can also `(require racket/function)` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it weren't already implemented, `identity` is trivial to code:

```
(define (identity x) x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`identity` is just a name for a function that takes one argument and returns that argument.  It works like this:

```
> (identity 4)
4
> (identity "hello world")
"hello world"
```